# PySimpleGui save Multiline as .txt

Tags: python, save, multiline, pysimplegui

I want to save Multiline (PySimpleGui) as .txt.

```
[sg.Multiline(
              enter_submits=True,
               key='_LOG_'
))]
```

The program writes into it

```
window['_LOG_'].print('something')
```

and when it's done it should automatically save it as .txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event loop, `values` is the content of some elements before your actions for that event, so you cannot use the value of `values['_LOG_']` to save your log file.

Try use method of `get` of `sg.Multiline` to get current content of `sg.Multiline` element.

```py
        window['_LOG_'].print("Hello World")

        with open("LogFile.txt", "wt", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            f.write(window['_LOG_'].get())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your *key* for this. Like:

```
import io

with io.open("data.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(values['_LOG_'])
f.close()
```

Comment: Yeah already tried that but it's not working :/

Comment: =(. Does your loop read the values? Like: window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()

Comment: It work only if the content of `sg,Multiline` element not changed after event generated. Open file with `with` statement will auto close the file, so `f.close()` is not necessary.